# WPF: Minecraft Game Coordinates to WPF Canvas Coordinates

Tags: wpf, canvas, wpf-controls, minecraft

I've been trying to get coordinates from Minecraft and putting them on an WPF canvas for a map viewer. However, most of it does not work and it is not centered. How would you go about with doing this?

Help is appreciated!

*Update #1:* 
I'll be a bit more descriptive of what I want. I'd like to show positions (not images or terrain and stuff) on a WPF Canvas. What I am trying to do is making a navigation system showing lines from certain coordinates to other coordinates. One thing I've tried was making the canvas as big as a Minecraft map, but that didn't work well.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85603/A-WPF-custom-control-for-zooming-and-panning I've been using that with no problems, but the thing is that I want to actually translate in game coordinates to coordinates on the maps for waypoints and such. 
Sorry for the lack of detail at first!

Comment: Maybe a `Grid` with a certain number of rows and columns would be more suitable?  Someone might be able to help you if you provide more details (code/screenshots) that exactly describe the problem.

Comment: I've updated mine to be more detailed.